# Facebook integration with website using facebook login button plugin and store user crenditials to database

Tags: php, facebook

I am using Facebook [Login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/) Button to integrate with facebook in my website.
But, I don't know how to save the username etc(userdata on facebook) from facebook to my database on login through facebook . How this can be done ?

Currently, when clicking the facebook login button an window is opened, we can enter the facebook username and password and it will be connected.

How to enter into php part while login to store user datas on facebook and if already exist login to site without store any data  ?

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=987654321";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


   // facebook login button

<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1" ></div>
```

Comment: Start with discovering [FB PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk)

Comment: so you want to store users facebook login and password in your database?

Comment: @Asdfg No, only username/email_id, other details like access token ..

Comment: @Jusnit: so get php sdk and retrieve them. PS: you don't need to store access token ever

Comment: @Jusnit, the access_token can change depending on permissions and other factors so you shouldn't store it. Also your best bet is to check their application guidelines. I think you can store their uid, but there might be other implications on what you are allowed to store which means you could break TOS by storing certain things- obviously you can specifically request these  details on your own form, or get the permission to access it via the graph api when you need it. Here's a link for you https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Answer (score 1):

Please download the facebook php sdk.

Below is an example for connecting to facebook.

```
<?php session_start();
require 'src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));

// See if there is a user from a cookie
$user = $facebook->getUser();
//$session = $facebook->getSession();
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    //echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
    $user = null;
  }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <body>
    <?php if ($user) { 
    foreach($user_profile as $skey => $sval)
    {
        $_SESSION["$skey"]=$sval;   
    }   
    $_SESSION['fb_name']=$user_profile['name']; //get facebook username and set it in session
    $_SESSION['fb_id']=$user_profile['id']; //get facebook id and set it in session
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    $_SESSION['fb_logout']= $logoutUrl;

     ?>
      <pre>            
        <?php //print htmlspecialchars(print_r($user_profile, true)) ?>
      </pre> 
    <?php } else { ?>
      <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
    <?php } ?>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>               
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>', 
          cookie: true, 
          xfbml: true,
          oauth: true
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    window.location.href="index.php";
          //window.location.reload();
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      };
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In login portion check like this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['fb_id'])) {
//check whether the entry for this fb_id already exists in db
//if not exists insert id and name into db, else get username from db for this fb_id
}
```